# Read iPad/iPhone Disk like USB Flash Drive

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, usb

I need to get some direction on how to read the contents of an iPhone/iPad device like it's a usb flash drive.  I have downloaded iExplorer and phone disk from macroplant, which do exactly what I need, but I need this functionality integrated in my app.

Not looking for a full solution (won't reject it either :)), but I need somewhere to start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is **manzana** open source library (C#) that lets you read/write files from/to the iPhone, list directory contents and other file and directory related functions.

I saw links on google code but wasn't able to downloaded sources. May be you will find.

Good luck!

P.S. Also view this project: http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/

Comment: Thanks. I can't get to the manzana project and the iphonebrowser requires a jailbroken device.  I'm sure there's a way to do this.  I downloaded explorer and it works great.  I need the same functionality embedded in my app.